# Why are WebMvcConfigurer override methods not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I created a project with Spring Boot. I am configuring the basic config, but there is a problem in implementing WebMvcConfigurer.

addInterceptors works well, but addViewControllers and addResourceHandlers don't work. There are no errors, but these two methods don't apply.

I think I set it all right, but I can not find the cause. Can I see why?

[Project Structure]

> java
>   --me
>   ----eastglow
>   ------sample
>   --------controller
>   ----------SampleController.java
>   ------config
>   --------RootContextConfig.java
>   --------Application.java
>   --------DispatcherServletConfig.java

[RootContextConfig.java]

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"me.eastglow.*"},
        excludeFilters = {@Filter(Controller.class)}
)
public class RootContextConfig {
}
```

[Application.java]

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(DispatcherServletConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("appServlet", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.json");
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.do");
    }

}
```

[DispatcherServletConfig.java]

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages={"me.eastglow.*"},
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters={@Filter(Controller.class)},
        excludeFilters={@Filter(Service.class), @Filter(Repository.class)}
)
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource(
        value={"classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", "classpath:log4jdbc.log4j2.properties"},
        ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class DispatcherServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final static String[] RESOURCE_HANDLER_PATH = {"/favicon.ico"
            , "/image/**"
            , "/js/**"};
    private final static String[] RESOURCE_HANDLER_LOCATION = {"/resources/favicon.ico"
            , "/resources/image/"
            , "/resources/js/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        CacheControl cacheControl = CacheControl.empty().cachePrivate();

        registry.addResourceHandler(RESOURCE_HANDLER_PATH).addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_HANDLER_LOCATION).setCacheControl(cacheControl);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/member/login.do");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BusinessInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolvers.add(internalResourceViewResolver);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);


        return resolver;
    }
}
```

[Updated]

```
public class DispatcherServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final static String[] RESOURCE_HANDLER_PATH = {"/favicon.ico"
            , "/image/**"
            , "/js/**"};
    private final static String[] RESOURCE_HANDLER_LOCATION = {"/resources/favicon.ico"
            , "/resources/image/"
            , "/resources/js/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        CacheControl cacheControl = CacheControl.empty().cachePrivate();

        registry.addResourceHandler(RESOURCE_HANDLER_PATH).addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_HANDLER_LOCATION).setCacheControl(cacheControl);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/member/login.do");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BusinessInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
}

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(jacksonMessageConverter()); //Json Message Converter
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()); // File Transfer Message Converter
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setOrder(2);
        resolvers.add(internalResourceViewResolver);

        JsonViewResolver jsonViewResolver = new JsonViewResolver();
        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver);

        resolvers.add(beanNameViewResolver());

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();

        configurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{"/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml"});
        configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);

        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setOrder(1);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    class JsonViewResolver implements ViewResolver {
        @Override
        public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) {
            MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
            view.setPrettyPrint(true);
            view.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            view.setDisableCaching(true);
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Bean(name="beanNameViewResolver")
    public BeanNameViewResolver beanNameViewResolver(){
        BeanNameViewResolver beanNameViewResolver = new BeanNameViewResolver();
        beanNameViewResolver.setOrder(0);
        return beanNameViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name="jacksonMessageConverter")
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter(){
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot, then why are you working around Spring Boot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working around Spring Boot instead of using it.

For starters remove the `onStartup` method of your `Application` class. Spring Boot takes care of all of that.

Next ditch your `RootContextConfig`.

2 cleanup your `DispatcherServletConfig`

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
        value={"classpath:log4jdbc.log4j2.properties"},
        ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class DispatcherServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/member/login.do");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new BusinessInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Now in your `application.properties` (or create one) add the following

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.resources.cache.cache-private=true
```

The mappings should work by default else place your `js` and `images` inside `src/main/resources/static` or `src/main/resources/public`.

This is all you need if you properly use Spring Boot (instead of working around it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question. I want to add a ViewResolver of BeanNameViewResolver or JsonViewResolver. Does Spring Boot handle all of these things? I have updated the body of the code I want to add. I would be grateful if you could let me know which of the modified codes you need.

Comment: `BeanNameViewResolver` is active by default. AFAIK there is no `JsonViewResolver` and you should be good to use a `@RestController` and let the other Spring infrastructue (`HttpMessageConverter` s) handle JSON/XML. Else just define it as an `@Bean` .